# Can Meteor call a method on the server twice if the client gets disconnected?

Tags: meteor

In [LivedataConnection, line 357](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp/livedata_connection.js#L357), there's a comment that says:

```
// Sends the method message to the server. May be called additional times if
// we lose the connection and reconnect before receiving a result.
```

Does this mean that if a client calls a method and gets disconnected before the method returns, it will re-call that message when it reconnects? What if that method isn't idempotent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, yes, as of version 1.0. Meteor methods are not idempotent. I've reported this issue, as have others, and it's basically confirmed by a core developer:

> https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2407#issuecomment-52375372

The best way to fix this in most cases is to try and write a unique key to the database, associating with a method request, or to make use of some other clever conditional database updates. There are some discussions about how to do that in these threads:

- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/j1YF7JO5Rdo/cYHR5kbhC8UJ
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26430334/586086